# What is the equivalent tool TC (Traffic Control) for Solaris?

Tags: networking, solaris, tc

I would like to know if anyone knows a way to emulate what [TC](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) does on Linux. I have some scripts that I would like to port to Solaris.

Comment: This is probably a part of the answer: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1458/gfkci.html . check dladm and flowadm

Comment: Yeah, `flowadm` it's what I was looking for.